# What does "tie up" mean in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms, phrasal-verbs

This context comes from a youtube video about the financial scandal including the Enron company.

> Now let's fast forward one year and see how you did. So it turn out the stock didn't go up like everyone had projected. In fact, it went down just a tad. What was in the 80$ range when you invested is now in the 50 to 60 cent range so you've effectively you've lost all your money. I'm making light of it here but there were thousands of people that experienced this including the Enron employees. They invested heavily in 401k and retirement plans that were **tied up** in Enron stock.

a: to place or invest in such a manner as to make unavailable for other purposes

b: to cause to be linked so as to depend on or relate to something

Comment: I would definitely say (a).

Comment: I agree that (a) is almost certainly what is meant here.  When we mean (b), we usually say "tied up **with**".

Answer (score 1):

Definitely A. Although the money is linked to Enron’s stock effectively depending on it, the money from the 401k’s in that sentence isn’t causing the dependency. The employees who invested in Enron did the actual causing.